# Eeek! The links in the mobile inbox have disappeared!

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, mobile-web, global-inbox

On the mobile site, the links in the inbox aren't links anymore. Here's a screenshot (click it to enlarge):

[image]

I have also reproduced it [on a computer by clicking the "mobile" link in the footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuhX2.png).

Comment: There sure that been a lot of Eeeeks today.

Comment: @bluefeet Each one has one more `e` than the previous :P

Comment: Sorry to be so pedantic but three "eee" means something really major is broken i.e. can't post questions anymore. This one is medium so level two Eeek is enough. :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Aww, I just wanted to continue the pattern :P I suppose pleasing the Eeeeek gods is more important, though.

Comment: How do you know the devs are working hard to improve the site? Three new bug reports in the last hour :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting!

Mixup with markdown and with variable names. And not enough coffee.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Someone get this man some coffee so he'll stop breaking everything.

Comment: @animuson you think coffee can be air mailed? :)